# Using Redux for making protected routes with React-Navigation (v.3 or v.4)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

How can we use redux to create protected routes in react-navigation?

Consider I have a redux store containing following state

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.profileInfo.isAuthenticated,
    isLoaded: state.profileInfo.isLoaded,
    googleProfileLoading: state.profileInfo.googleProfileLoading
  }
};
```

And I am using React-navigation to navigate user.

```
const loginNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    login: {
      screen: Login
    },
    signup: {
      screen: Signup
    }
  },
  {
    headerMode: "none"
  }
)

const allRoutes = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    home: {
      screen: loginNavigation
    },
    user: {
      screen: user

  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "home"
  }
);

const App = createAppContainer(allRoutes);
```

Now if user is not logged in, I want redirect to login screen.

In simple react-redux, this is what I usually used to do: https://github.com/irohitb/SelfieApp/blob/master/client/src/routes.js

Can someone help me in figuring out how can we create protected routes in react-native, redux and react-navigation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

react-navigation has `createSwitchNavigator` exactly for cases like this [Authentication Flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html).

You have to group your protected routes in one MainStack. Use `createStackNavigator`:

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    events: { screen: EventsScreen },
    profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
    ...
  {
    initialRouteName: "home"
  }
);
```

Then, config your authentication stack, again using `createStackNavigator`:

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
    login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    register: { screen: RegisterScreen },
    forgot: { screen: ForgottenPasswordScreen },
    ...
});
```

And now is coming the `createSwitchNavigator` - to load the `MainStack` stack or the `AuthStack`:

```
const Routes = createSwitchNavigator({
    initialLoading: InitialLoadingScreen,
    auth: AuthStack,
    all: MainStack,
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'initialLoading',
});

export default createAppContainer(Routes);
```

The `createSwitchNavigator` will load `InitialLoadingScreen` that holds the logic if the user is authenticated or not:

```
class InitialLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.bootstrapAsync();
    }

    bootstrapAsync = async () => {
        // Load the home screen for the logged in users 
        if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
            return this.props.navigation.navigate('home');
        }

        // load the Auth screen if the user is NOT logged in
        this.props.navigation.navigate('login');
    }

    // Render any loading content that you like here
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ settings }) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.profileInfo.isAuthenticated,
    isLoaded: state.profileInfo.isLoaded,
    googleProfileLoading: state.profileInfo.googleProfileLoading
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(InitialLoadingScreen);
```

As you can see, you can connect `InitialLoadingScreen` to the redux store, to access any data and use it for your routing logic :)

Comment: Also, it is good to note that using switch navigator is actually better in many cases. Because it will unmount not focused route, which frees up memory.

Comment: @Hristo, Whenever my redux state changes, wouldn't my class InitialLoadingScreen re-render? hence on every state change, wouldn't it redirect to  `return this.props.navigation.navigate('home')` or `this.props.navigation.navigate('login');` , I mean consider `const MainStack` from your example, wouldn't it redirect to initial screen (i.e home) whenever my redux state changes?

Comment: @Ziyo can you please go through the above comment and see if you could help me out

Comment: No, it shouldn't re-render. The switch component is carrying about it to happen only once, when you load it

Comment: In each redux state change your `render()` methods gets called. No you will not be redirected, because `bootstrapAsync` method is called from the `constructor`. Constructor gets called when the component is instantiating (once).

Answer (score 3):

So you have one redux state variable `isAuthenticated`.

In every screen you'll need to check for this state, if not logged in then thow user to login screen and reset navigation stack.

you can check in any life cycle method which will be called on first run,

for e.g., `constructor`, `componentWillMount`, `componentDidMount`, etc...

for redux state checking,

```
if(!this.props.isAuthenticated){
 this.props.logoutAction();
 this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");//Login or whatever your first screen is...
}
```

and for clearing whole stack,you'll need to create action which we called in above section.

```
export const logoutAction = () => {
  return dispatch => dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS });
};
```

and you have to change some logic in file where you have written combine reducer's code,

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  loginReducers: LoginReducers,
  ...
  ...
});

export default (rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type == LOGOUT_SUCCESS) {
    state = undefined;
  }
  return appReducer(state, action);
});
```

this will reset whole reducer.

Now if you want to make logout button then `onPress` of button just change `isAuthenticated` to `false` and fire navigate method and logout action that's all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-native router flux for navigation

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-router-flux

sample:

```
<Text
    style={alerts.btn}
    onPress={
        () => Actions.question(
            // send data 
            {
                'code': data_1,
            })}>
    Go to Home
</Text>
```